# Injecting services in Grails Cxf web services causes getter/setter generation

Tags: grails, dependency-injection, cxf

I have a cxf web service simplified as below. My problem is that if I inject services like below, the generated wsdl will have setParameterService/getParameterService and getMessageSource/setMessageSource methods as well. What should I do if I don't want to expose them as webservices?

```
@WebService(portName = "OrganizationPort", serviceName = "OrganizationService", name = "OrganizationService", targetNamespace = "http://akum.compugroup.com")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.WRAPPED, use = Use.LITERAL, style = Style.DOCUMENT)
class OrganizationWebService {

def parameterService
def messageSource

static expose = EndpointType.JAX_WS

@WebMethod
@WebResult
Organization kurumSorgulama(@WebParam(partName = "KurumSorgulamaTalep", name = "KurumSorgulamaTalep", targetNamespace = "http://akum.compugroup.com") String kurumKodu) { 

    return organization
}

@WebMethod
@WebResult
Organization authorize(@WebParam(partName = "KurumSorgulamaTalep", name = "KurumSorgulamaTalep", targetNamespace = "http://akum.compugroup.com") String kurumKodu) {

    return organization
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified the code a bit, but this should get you running.  Make the service endpoints private and then annotate them with @AutoWired

```
@WebService(portName = "OrganizationPort", serviceName = "OrganizationService", name = "OrganizationService", targetNamespace = "http://akum.compugroup.com")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
class OrganizationService {

    @Autowired
    private BoatService boatService
    @Autowired
    private CarService carService

    static expose = EndpointType.JAX_WS

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult
    String goFish(@WebParam(partName = "KurumSorgulamaTalep", name = "KurumSorgulamaTalep", targetNamespace = "http://akum.compugroup.com") String kurumKodu) {
        boatService.fish()
    }

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult
    String goHonk(@WebParam(partName = "KurumSorgulamaTalep", name = "KurumSorgulamaTalep", targetNamespace = "http://akum.compugroup.com") String kurumKodu) {
        carService.honkHorn()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also drop the static expose = EndpointType.JAX_WS since you have the @WebService annotation on there which does the same thing.

Comment: I added this example to the github project at https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-cxf/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/cxf/test/OrganizationService.groovy and you can invoke it with SOAP UI if you get the project source and do a run app on it and use localhost:8080/grails-cxf/services/organization?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it for a Grails app, but normally you can use `@XmlTransient`. Also you may need to use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` at the class level.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace:

```
@WebService(portName = "OrganizationPort", serviceName = "OrganizationService", name = "OrganizationService", targetNamespace = "http://akum.compugroup.com")
```

with:

```
@GrailsCxfEndpoint
```

*@GrailsCxfEndpoint* automatically excludes all the getters and setters.

But then you would loose the ability to set *portName*, *serviceName*, *name* and *targetNamespace*. That's exactly the problem I have at the moment.

Mixing *@GrailsCxfEndpoint* with *@WebService* is also no solution as it exposes the getters and setters again.